# Cannot read property 'decode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, gtfs

I have been playing around with the General Transit Feed Specification - Realtime, and I am following exactly the example given on google's documentation:

https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/examples/nodejs-sample

for JavaScript, using my cities local transit feed, however I keep encountering the following error:

```
var feed = GtfsRealtimeBindings.FeedMessage.decode(body);
                                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'decode' of undefined
```

I have a working implementation in python that follows their example for that, so I can verify with certainty that the feed is the correct format.

I am running the code using the instruction:

```
node index.js
```

My package.json includes all the relevant dependencies, and I have installed using npm the required packages.
I have searched far and wide for a solution to this error but have had no luck. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the current example code on GitHub 
(https://github.com/MobilityData/gtfs-realtime-bindings/tree/master/nodejs#example-code)
it seems you're missing `transit_realtime` in between:

```
GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(body);
```

Answer (score 1):

On the example there is a link to the github of the Javascript language binding. The github example differs from the documentation example. I figure the documentation is simply out of date.

the line in the google documentation example

`var feed = GtfsRealtimeBindings.FeedMessage.decode(body);`

should be `var feed = GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(body);` note the inclusion of `.transit_realtime`.

Alternatively this could be expressed in the line:

`var GtfsRealtimeBindings = require('gtfs-realtime-bindings');`

as `var GtfsRealtimeBindings = require('gtfs-realtime-bindings').transit_realtime;`

and the google documentation example code beyond that line would remain as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import gtfs-realtime-bindings by referencing the transit_realtime property. It's a change from the old protobuf.js bindings generator, but this is done to separate namespaces.

It won't work

```
cont GtfsRealtimeBindings = require('gtfs-realtime-bindings');
```

It will:

```
const GtfsRealtimeBindings = require('gtfs-realtime-bindings').transit_realtime;
```

Now you can get feedMessage and decode it.

```
const { FeedMessage, FeedHeader, FeedEntity, VehiclePosition } = GtfsRealtimeBindings;
```